# Is there a difference between `(param i32 i32)` and `(param i32) (param i32)` in web assembly?

Tags: webassembly

I've seen plenty of multi-value uses in readable web assembly code (.wat files), but what is the key difference between both?

Examples:

- [func (param i32 i32)](https://github.com/WebAssembly/multi-value/blob/master/proposals/multi-value/Overview.md#Examples)
- [func (param i32) (param f32)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Understanding_the_text_format#getting_and_setting_locals_and_parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no functional difference. It is document in the specification [here](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/types.html#abbreviations):

> Multiple anonymous parameters or results may be combined into a single declaration

Comment: And in terms of performance/ practical use, which is the recommended way to go?

Comment: @Anatoly The compilation won’t be much affected and the resulting binary is exactly the same. Not sure if there’s any preferred way though naming parameters may be a good idea usually

Comment: @Anatoly As far as I know, the specification does not have a recommendation on the matter. Both are equally valid. That makes them practical in different scenarios. The performance (for long lists of parameters/results) might be slightly affected only in the parser or the generator. The choice might depend from the use case. The word "may" is used that means "optionally" (ignoring the capitalization) by RFC 2119 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119.html)

Comment: Alright. @ NikolayHandzhiyski and @ Sami Kuhmonen, looks like I confused myself because it was the same thing. Thank you!